# CSS or jQuery hover effect to increase a fixed box and show absolute position larger version

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How can I make my colour boxes increase in size (in same position, guessing absolute position so it does not affect the other positions of colours) when you hover will show a larger version of the colour when you hover. Would this use background image size?

I have added a image for a test on the red one.

```css
#product_color_select li {
 display: inline-block;
 width: 30px;
 height: 25px;
 text-indent: -999999em;
 cursor: pointer;
}
/* interior colours */
#product_color_select li.eco-weave {
 background-color: #beaaaa;
}
#product_color_select li.aubergine-dream {
 background-color: #382643;
}
#product_color_select li.lime-citrus {
 background-color: #99a366;
}
#product_color_select li.blue-jazz {
 background-color: #435fa1;
}
#product_color_select li.sakura-pink {
 background-color: #bf3253;
}
#product_color_select li.hot-chocolate {
 background-color: #3b2b28;
}
#product_color_select li.tundra-spring {
 background-color: #c5c1d0;
}
#product_color_select li.black-sapphire {
 background-color: #131114;
}
#product_color_select li.luscious-grey {
 background-color: #7a6772;
}
#product_color_select li.wildberry-deluxe {
 background-image: url('http://2015.ambientlounge.com/design/themes/ambientlounge/media/images/swatches/mini/wildberry-deluxe.png');
}
```

```html
<ul class="fabric-select" id="product_color_select">
    <li class=" eco-weave" data-value="742" title="Eco Weave">Eco Weave</li>
    <li class=" blue-jazz" data-value="749" title="Blue Jazz">Blue Jazz</li>
    <li class=" sakura-pink" data-value="743" title="Sakura Pink">Sakura Pink</li>
    <li class="selected luscious-grey" data-value="744" title="Luscious Grey">Luscious Grey</li>
    <li class=" lime-citrus" data-value="748" title="Lime Citrus">Lime Citrus</li>
    <li class=" hot-chocolate" data-value="741" title="Hot Chocolate">Hot Chocolate</li>
    <li class=" black-sapphire" data-value="746" title="Black Sapphire">Black Sapphire</li>
    <li class=" wildberry-deluxe" data-value="727" title="Wildberry Deluxe">Wildberry Deluxe</li>
    <li class=" tundra-spring" data-value="747" title="Tundra Spring">Tundra Spring</li>
    <li class=" aubergine-dream" data-value="745" title="Aubergine Dream">Aubergine Dream</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Increase width on :hover ?

Comment: Yea width and height on hover would work sure, be nice to increase in each corner if that makes sense expanding the current one

Comment: Something like **[this](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/ofw4ktkd/)**?

Comment: No, a little like the answer below - the effect anyway but not sacaling the image as making it poor quality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Used CSS3 `scale` property on the hover of the element. Hope this helps.

In addition you can use the `transition` property to add some easing.

```css
#product_color_select li {
 display: inline-block;
 width: 30px;
 height: 25px;
 text-indent: -999999em;
 cursor: pointer;
vertical-align:top;
}
#product_color_select li:hover{ 
-webkit-transform:scale(1.2);  
-moz-transform:scale(1.2);
transform:scale(1.2);
}
/* interior colours */
#product_color_select li.eco-weave {
 background-color: #beaaaa;
}
#product_color_select li.aubergine-dream {
 background-color: #382643;
}
#product_color_select li.lime-citrus {
 background-color: #99a366;
}
#product_color_select li.blue-jazz {
 background-color: #435fa1;
}
#product_color_select li.sakura-pink {
 background-color: #bf3253;
}
#product_color_select li.hot-chocolate {
 background-color: #3b2b28;
}
#product_color_select li.tundra-spring {
 background-color: #c5c1d0;
}
#product_color_select li.black-sapphire {
 background-color: #131114;
}
#product_color_select li.luscious-grey {
 background-color: #7a6772;
}
#product_color_select li.wildberry-deluxe {
 background-image: url('http://2015.ambientlounge.com/design/themes/ambientlounge/media/images/swatches/mini/wildberry-deluxe.png');
}
```

```html
<ul class="fabric-select" id="product_color_select">
    <li class=" eco-weave" data-value="742" title="Eco Weave">Eco Weave</li>
    <li class=" blue-jazz" data-value="749" title="Blue Jazz">Blue Jazz</li>
    <li class=" sakura-pink" data-value="743" title="Sakura Pink">Sakura Pink</li>
    <li class="selected luscious-grey" data-value="744" title="Luscious Grey">Luscious Grey</li>
    <li class=" lime-citrus" data-value="748" title="Lime Citrus">Lime Citrus</li>
    <li class=" hot-chocolate" data-value="741" title="Hot Chocolate">Hot Chocolate</li>
    <li class=" black-sapphire" data-value="746" title="Black Sapphire">Black Sapphire</li>
    <li class=" wildberry-deluxe" data-value="727" title="Wildberry Deluxe">Wildberry Deluxe</li>
    <li class=" tundra-spring" data-value="747" title="Tundra Spring">Tundra Spring</li>
    <li class=" aubergine-dream" data-value="745" title="Aubergine Dream">Aubergine Dream</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Is there anyway to no use scale as its scaling the background image - the image is already set as a larger image size so the LI just needs to increase i guess so quality is still good on the image.

Comment: Using scale is the perfect effect!! exactly how i want it but dont want to scale the background image as its large already.

Comment: You can set the initial scale value of all the `li` to some value lesser than 1 and on hover set the value to 1 i.e the default size.

Comment: Tried that, but its not really working out to how i need it. Making intial thamb smaller, positions like padding / margins out so think i need some other solution maybe... not sure. large size is 200x143 for the full size image so prob want to go to about half of that.

Comment: @James please share  a fiddles link of your work with the images

Comment: Hey sorry, what i ended up doing in the end was had a larger thumbnail to the right of the mini thumbnails and just changed the image when you hover etc... thanks for your help though.... sorry just getting back though, very tight deadline so been doing crazy 20/22hr days :(

Comment: However your Answer would 100% help someone else with scaling on hover so going to mark as good +1 :)